# Is there a way get to the value instead of the reference of an object

Tags: memory-management, vala

I would like to do something like :

```
var data_copy = original_data;
```

And then do some stuff on data_copy without modifying original_data.
Data_copy and original_data are objects.

Is there a direct way to do that in vala ?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the object. For `struct`s, this happens automatically. For objects, there isn't a common way. Some objects have a `dup()` method that can do this, but it is not universal. There's no guaranteed safe way to duplicate an object since it might reference system resources or other things which cannot be duplicated.

Comment: "There's no guaranteed safe way to duplicate an object since it might reference system resources or other things which cannot be duplicated." So don't duplicate the resource; duplicate the reference thereto. In other words, perform a shallow copy.

Comment: How would that work for objects that are not reference counted? If an object is singly-owned, it can't be shallow-copied.

Comment: Ah, touche. Even still, the compiler can tell whether an object owns any resources or not, and could thus permit shallow copying of most objects, no? I'm not particularly familiar with Vala, so pardon my hypothesizing.

Comment: Unlikely. Since, the GObject class hierarchy can have private implementations, with no way for the compiler to determine how to duplicate them.

Comment: The 'dup' method would be defined on the object, and it's only a shallow copy, so privacy shouldn't be a concern so long as the object (or rather, the compiler as it's compiling the object) can tell if the object is the owner of each of its members. Or is ownership a private implementation detail of the member itself?

Comment: Private members in Vala are stripped at compile time, unlike, say Java, where they are always visible to the VM. The compiler can't tell if a superclass has private members.